# @Transactional annotation required due to 'org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread' exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

So, I read that the best place to put the @Transactional annotation was outside the DAO classes which contains the db access methods, like in a service class which use those methods.

Now, the problem is, once I've already remove this annotations from the DAO classes, I launch the DAO test methods and the aforementioned exception raised. I put back the annotations in the DAO classes and this exception doesn't raises anymore.

Then my question is: how can I clear my DAOs of this annotations and still have my tests working?

Let's add some code:

**DAO class**

```
public class UserDAO  extends IDAO implements IUserDAO {


    @Override
    //@Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public User get(int idUser) {
        return (User) currentSession().get(User.class,idUser);
    }}
```

**IDAO Class**

```
public abstract class IDAO {

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session currentSession()
    {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

**Test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/app-context.xml" })
public class UserDAOTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDAO userDAO;

    @Test
    public void testGetUser() throws Exception {
        User user = userDAO.get(2);
        assertNotNull(user);
    }
}
```

**app-config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/waldb" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.wal.serverside.persistence.domain.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.wal.serverside.persistence.DAO.UserDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wal.serverside.persistence" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Did you try putting @Transactional annotation on the test function?

Comment: yep, but didn't work :( Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosh, how much stupid can I be?

My test class didn't extend from **AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests**, so there were nor transaction nor session inside my tests.

This fixed it all:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/app-context.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional
public class UserDAOTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests  {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDAO userDAO;

    public void setUserDAO(IUserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetUser() throws Exception {
        User user = userDAO.get(2);
        assertNotNull(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, in my project I didn't use AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests and all is working good. I think the problem was in that you extend your class from AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests. So if you will not extend any class all should be working too.

Comment: I've never used the AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.  Simply use the \@RunWith, \@ContextConfiguration and \@Transactional annotations, and that's it.   And if your transaction manager has the bean name "transactionManager", it's not necessary to explicitly call it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put not only *@Transactional* annotaition on your test class but also *@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)*.  Where you explicitly set the name of the transaction manager that you have defined in xml.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/app-context.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor={Exception.class})
public class UserDAOTest {
     ...
}
```

Also transaction will not work if you explicitly create the application context in your test method and then get the bean from it:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...);
SomeDAO someDAO = (SomeDAO) appContext.getBean(...);
```

instad of inhjecting it.

But I see this is not your case.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to solve it cause I'm getting the same exception. And yep, I don't need to get my UserDAO manually since @Autowired does it for me :)