# No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I have problem with:

> No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow
>   creation of non-transactional one here

when testing my project.

I use Spring 2.0.7(this is must in that project) and Hibernate 3. I have

- SessionFactory defined
- Transaction manager defined(with session factory injected)
- `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` - 
  annotations for transactions switched on

I have annotated my tests with:

@Test

@Transactional

and inherited AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests

=> I got this error:No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Only way I can overcome it is to use: `TransactionStatus transaction = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition);`

in test before I call

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(myObject);
```

Any suggestions? Or better: how it works? Why it can not create transactional session ? Why no hibernate session is bound ? I have read something about it but it is still not clear to me. I think that I did everything to make it working but obviously it was not sufficient.

Thx in advance,

Stepik

Comment: What is the transactionManager - is it HibernateTransactionManager?

Comment: <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory">
   <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: It would be good if you can show the relevant snippets of your test code and configuration.  From the description you have provided it should work, but there are too many subtle things that can cause problems.  Looking at actual code / config will help.  Otherwise you can enable info/debug logging for spring and see if you can notice anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem consist in that you extend your class from AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests. Try to remove inheritance (it should work without it). Or try to extend your class from AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests class.

You can look [here at similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608518/transactional-annotation-required-due-to-org-hibernate-hibernateexception-no/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case a `base-package` was missed. One like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname" />
```